# toFixed() behavior on performance.now()

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance.now

When using `toFixed` on `performance.now`, it reveals some digits which I assume normally rounded. But it seems, the range changes based on platform.

On chrome(v87.0.4280.66), it can get up to 35 digits

```
window.performance.now().toFixed(35); // "241989.00499999945168383419513702392578125"
```

On node.js(v15.2.1), it's only up to 28.

```
performance.now().toFixed(28) // "1092.9840000011026859283447265625"
```

Same behavior exist on `performance.timeOrigin` too. I assume that it is possible to make much more accurate measurements with `performance.now()` but that accuracy depends on hardware and software factors so they just keep that accuracy on minimum standart.

1. Does using `toFixed(100)` on `performance.now()` makes it more accurate?
2. What factors affect range of `performance.now()`?
3. Can we safely say that `(performance.timeOrigin + performance.now()).toFixed(12)` let's us measure the time accurate up to almost femtoseconds(10⁻¹⁵) or at least much much more accurate than the `Date.now()`?

Comment: I'm not sure why you believe `toFixed` to make the number *more* accurate. It might very well be *less* accurate as it exposes the innate imprecision of binary floating point number representation.

Comment: `performance.now` still returns a `number`, which is an IEEE-754 double, so it is bounded by that precision limit. `.toFixed(100)` does not make sense.

Comment: Why do you think it adds non-zero-value digits instead of simply adding zeros? This could make it less accurate indeed, there is no info about precision limit of ```performance.now()``` and ```performance.timeOrigin```

Comment: `performance.now` is not accurate in browsers anyway to mitigate timing attacks like sceptre/meltdown

Comment: In node it's fairly accurate but not _that_ accurate, you can use process.hrtime which is about as accurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node's `performance.now` is literally:

```js
function now() {
  const hr = process.hrtime();
  return hr[0] * 1000 + hr[1] / 1e6;
}
```

Its accuracy is *nanoseconds*. (So not 26 digits after the point that's meaningless in that API). This just calls `uv_hrtime` (see node_process_methods.cc) which does [clock_gettime](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/e4087dedf837f415056a45a838f639a3d9dc3ced/src/unix/posix-hrtime.c#L32-L34) which is just a [standard way to get nanosecond time](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime).

In browsers the situation is worse - because of timing attacks that do fingerprinting or cache value extraction `performance.now` is less accurate:

> To offer protection against timing attacks and fingerprinting, the precision of performance.now() might get rounded depending on browser settings.

So you can really on rely on milliseconds value.

What it [returns](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/blink/renderer/core/timing/performance.cc;l=988;drc=3e4244d8f328164b9594b2cce70d105a243a995c;bpv=1;bpt=1) is [clamped in chrome](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/blink/renderer/core/timing/performance.cc;l=958-961;drc=3e4244d8f328164b9594b2cce70d105a243a995c;bpv=1;bpt=1). See `time_clamper.cc` for more info. Basically its percision is limited to:

```js
static constexpr double kResolutionSeconds = 5e-6;
```

Intentionally.

As the other answer points out `.toFixed` just formats a number as a string and is unrelated to any of this.

---

Note: the fact an API is precise to `X` digits does *not* in any way indicate digits after the Xth are zero. It only means that you can only rely on accuracy up to that digit.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like ```uv_hrtime()```
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node_perf_common.h

Comment: @BerkBecerenI know I'm one of the people who work on node and I reviewed some of that work when it landed :]

Comment: thank you for the details. 

there is something i can't understand; why does ```toFixed()``` just adds some _random_ digits instead of zero valued digits?

Comment: Not really (linking to an old spec version because it's shorter) http://es5.github.io/#x15.7.4.5 - check the Note there starting with " The output of toFixed may be more precise than toString" and see if it's still unclear - if it is read the algorithm in 15.7.4.5, if it still is: try going both through that algorithm and http://es5.github.io/#x9.8.1 for 1000000000000000128 to understand why the values are different.

Answer (score 0):

I think saying that `toFixed()` makes it more accurate is wrong.

Basically `toFixed()` only formats the input number.

As for the `performant.now()` it returns milliseconds value which represents the time elapsed since the time origin.

The time origin is a standard time which is considered to be the beginning of the current document's lifetime.

So from your question you could imagine that this value would be calculate differently across different platforms.

From [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp#The_time_origin):

- If the current Document is the first one loaded in the Window, the time origin is the time at which the browser context was created.
- If during the process of unloading the previous document which was loaded in the window, a confirmation dialog was displayed to let the user confirm whether or not to leave the previous page, the time origin is the time at which the user confirmed that navigating to the new page was acceptable.
- If neither of the above determines the time origin, then the time origin is the time at which the navigation responsible for creating the window's current Document took place.

Comment: As far as I know toFixed() only adds zero value digits to format input number. I don't see any reason for it to add extra non-zero digits instead of zero valued digits. Are there other cases where it adds non-zero-value digits too?


As for the ```performance.timeOrigin```, seems it doesn't important when the value created, sum of ```performance.timeOrigin``` and ```performance.now()``` yields same as ```Date.now()``` with extra precision.

Comment: Adding zeros is part of the toFixed(),  if the fixed value higher than the actual number, zeros are added to create the desired decimal length.

Comment: I am well aware of that, you can see it in the first and second sentence of my question. This is not I am asking, I'am asking _why it adds non-zero values **instead** of zero valued digits_ because as far as know adding zeros is the default behavior.